# Error in Server provisioning through Chef, Oracle Virtual Box and Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning

I am working on Chef- provisioning. I am trying to use chef-provisioning, Oracle Virtual Box and Vagrant for this purpose.  I executed this command:

```
"**gem install chef-provisioning chef-provisioning-vagrant**"
I got following error:
**Error: Could not find a valid gem 'chef-provisioning-vagrant'**
```

I moved ahead without bothering about it. And when I executed "chef-client -z vagrant_linux.rb simple.rb" I got following error:

```
**FATAL: LoadError: cannot load such file -- chef/provisioning_vagrant**
```

Why chef server is not able to locate "chef-provisioning-vagrant". Is this file renamed or changed or anything else. Could anybody help?

Regards
Manish Mehra

Answer (score 0):

If your box has no chef installed (e.g. you are using your own box made from scratch or you are using something like chef/debian-7.4), you only need to install the gem "chef". I don't know what the other gems you install are doing, but I am not aware of any issues with the normale "chef" gem:

```
sudo gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri chef
```

You can have a look at my repo where I take a plain debian box, install chef and some basic packages: https://github.com/Sgoettschkes/va/tree/master/debian7